# How do I get the PATH of a file that is in a known folder with a known extension, but with an unknown filename?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i'm working with an app for iOS, using an external framework for downloading an image. The file is saved in a known director inside documents directory, but the filename is unknown. Is an image, of a known extension. How can i get the filename or filepath? any idea?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate each file and check its extension

```
  NSDirectoryEnumerator* myFolderDir = [manager enumeratorAtPath:myfolder]; 
    for (id file in myFolderDir)
    {
        NSLog(@" file %@",file);
        if ([[file pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"YOUREXTENSION"]) 
        {
            NSString *path = [myfolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
            [self.Files addObject:path];

        }
    }
```

Comment: What if we have only single file for every type and we want to get that unique,I mean without looping as we know there are no multiple images/videos etc?

Comment: `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:yourPath error:&error]` should return array containing file path of all files in the directory. not sure though that was what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate contents of your directory.

```
NSString *directoryPath = @"your directory path";
NSString *extension = @"your extension";

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directoryPath error:&error];
if(!error) {
    for(NSString *item in directoryContent) {
        if([item rangeOfString:extension].location != NSNotFound) {
            // item is filename at directory path with current extension            
        }
    }
}
```